# Physical interpretation of the real-space field operator expansion of 1-body Hamiltonian

Tags: field-theory, many-body

I am now learning the field operator and I have some questions about the $\psi^{\dagger} \left( {\bf r} \right)$ expansion of the Hamiltonian with one-body potential. The Hamiltonian is written as
\begin{equation}
H = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\left( {\frac{{{\bf{p}}_i^2}}{{2m}} + {V^{(1)}}\left( {\bf{r}}_{i} \right)} \right)} 
\end{equation}
in the first-quantization.

First, if we consider the one-body Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\frac{{{{\bf{p}}^2}}}{{2m}} + {V^{(1)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)
\end{equation}
, we can solve for the eigenfunction and eigenvalue as $E_{n}$ and $\phi_{n} \left( {\bf r} \right)$. Let the creation operator for $\phi_{n} \left( {\bf r} \right)$ as $a^{\dagger}_{n}$, then the full Hamiltonian can be written in the second quantized version as 
\begin{equation}
H = \sum\limits_n {{E_n}a_n^\dagger {a_n}} 
\end{equation}

I understand what I mentioned above. However, when I start to use the continuous field $\psi^{\dagger} \left( {\bf r} \right)$ to express the Hamiltonian I got stuck with the physical interpretation.

In $\psi^{\dagger} \left( {\bf r} \right)$ expression, I know how to get the final expression as
\begin{equation}
H = \int {d{\bf{r}}{\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left[ { - \frac{{{\hbar ^2}}}{{2m}}{\nabla ^2} + {V^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} \right]{\psi ^{}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} 
\end{equation}

${\bf However}$ I don't know how to interpret the above expression, the following is my attempt : (I would to try use all-second-quantization language)

In expression
\begin{equation}
H = \int {d{\bf{r}}{\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left[ { - \frac{{{\hbar ^2}}}{{2m}}{\nabla ^2} + {V^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} \right]{\psi ^{}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} 
\end{equation}
The basis we use to expand the Hamiltonian is the eigenstate of position operator, therefore the meaning of $\psi^{\dagger} \left( {\bf r} \right)$ is the creation operator that creates a particle at position $\bf r$.

Since we now know the basis, what we can do to solve the Hamiltonian now is to consider
\begin{equation}
{ - \frac{{{\hbar ^2}}}{{2m}}{\nabla ^2} + {V^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)}
\end{equation}
and solve it, which is what I mention in the very beginning of this post to get $\phi_{n} \left( {\bf r} \right)$. The physical meaning of this $\phi_{n} \left( {\bf r} \right)$ is that it express the "amplitude" of the position eigenstate at $\bf r$.

Therefore, the eigenstate for the full Hamiltonian can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
\int {d{\bf{r}}{\phi _n}\left( {\bf{r}} \right){\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left| 0 \right\rangle } 
\end{equation}
where $\left| 0 \right\rangle$ is the vacuum state.

To prove that this is actually a eigenstate we can just do the 
\begin{align}
& H\int {d{\bf{r}}'{\phi _n}\left( {{\bf{r}}'} \right){\psi ^\dagger }\left( {{\bf{r}}'} \right)\left| 0 \right\rangle }  \\
&  = \left( {\int {d{\bf{r}}{\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left[ { - \frac{{{\hbar ^2}}}{{2m}}{\nabla ^2} + {V^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} \right]{\psi ^{}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} } \right)\int {d{\bf{r}}'{\phi _n}\left( {{\bf{r}}'} \right){\psi ^\dagger }\left( {{\bf{r}}'} \right)\left| 0 \right\rangle }  \\
&  = {E_n}\int {d{\bf{r}}{\phi _n}\left( {\bf{r}} \right){\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left| 0 \right\rangle } 
\end{align}

However, I think it is just doing the same thing as I did in the beginning of this post. Moreover, in my attempt, I can not see the many-body wavefunction like
${\left| {{n_1},{n_2},...} \right\rangle }$, which is what I expect to get because the field expression is to obtain the insight of many-body wavefunction.

All in all, I think I don't know how to "play" around this kind of expression :
\begin{equation}
H = \int {d{\bf{r}}{\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left[ { - \frac{{{\hbar ^2}}}{{2m}}{\nabla ^2} + {V^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} \right]{\psi ^{}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} 
\end{equation}

Can anyone gives me some suggestion?

Also, is there any advantage to express the full Hamiltonian in the form 
\begin{equation}
H = \int {d{\bf{r}}{\psi ^\dagger }\left( {\bf{r}} \right)\left[ { - \frac{{{\hbar ^2}}}{{2m}}{\nabla ^2} + {V^{\left( 1 \right)}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} \right]{\psi ^{}}\left( {\bf{r}} \right)} 
\end{equation} ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clarify a couple of basic facts which you probably already understand. The creation/annihilation and field operators are related by
\begin{align}
\psi(r) = \sum_n \phi_n(r) a_n \,,\quad a_n = \int \! dr \, \phi_n^*(r) \psi(r) \,.
\end{align}
Now, the two forms of the second-quantized Hamiltonian are equivalent.
\begin{align}
H = \sum_n E_n a^\dagger_n a_n = \int \! dr \, \psi^\dagger(r) \left(
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 + V^{(1)}(r) \right) \psi(r) \,.
\end{align}
The first form is convenient for algebraic manipulation, but it assumes we know the spectrum of the Hamiltonian. The second form is more cumbersome, but we can immediately write it down given a first-quantized Hamiltonian, without the need to know the spectrum.
Indeed, given a first-quantized Hamiltonian we can introduce the field operators which obey the algebra
\begin{align}
[\psi(r), \psi^\dagger(r')] = \delta(r-r') \,,\quad [\psi(r),\psi(r')]=[\psi^\dagger(r),\psi^\dagger(r')]=0
\end{align}
and write down the second-quantized Hamiltonian.
We can do this without knowing the eigenstates or eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian.
By the way, any single-particle operator (not just the Hamiltonian) can be promoted to a second-quantized operator in this way.

The second-quantized Hamiltonian naturally acts on many-body states. 
We can write down such states using creation operators, or using field operators (or both).
If we use creation operators then we get eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.
\begin{align}
\left| n_1, n_2, \dots \right> \sim (a^\dagger_1)^{n_1} (a^\dagger_2)^{n_2} \left| 0 \right> \,.
\end{align}
(The two sides are equal up to an overall normalization of the state.) 
We can act on these states using the either form of the second-quantized Hamiltonian.
Using the first equations written above (the relation between $a$ and $\psi$) we can go back and forth between the field operators and the annihilation/creation operators. When using the creation/annihilation operators we can use the algebra $[a_n,a^\dagger_m]=\delta_{nm}$ to compute. When using the field operators we can use their algebra to compute.
The result in both cases will be the same, in particular that these states have definite energy.

Notice that switching between $a,a^\dagger$ and $\psi,\psi^\dagger$ is simply a change of basis in operator space, with the wave functions $\phi_n(r)$ acting as the change-of-basis 'matrix'. Therefore computing using $a,a^\dagger$ or $\psi,\psi^\dagger$ is really doing the same calculation, just using a different basis.

We can also write many-body states using the field operator,
\begin{align}
\left| r_1,r_2,\dots \right> \sim
\psi^\dagger(r_1) \psi^\dagger(r_2) \cdots \left| 0 \right> \,.
\end{align}
Again, we can act on these states with the second-quantized Hamiltonian.
These are not eigenstates, so they will not have definite energy.
Their physical interpretation is that they describe localized particles at positions $r_1,r_2,\dots$. The algebra of the field operators will lead to Pauli's principle holding, namely the wave function will be symmetric under the exchange of positions.